# Discontinuity on an interval.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know how to prove discontinuity on a point . But how to prove discontinuity on an interval ? Is it sufficient to just prove a point on that interval is not continuous to imply that the interval is discontinuous ?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean prove at an arbitary point, then yes. A function is discontinuous on an interval is typically taken to mean discontinuous at every point. By showing it is discontinuous at an arbitrary point you show it must be discontinuous at every point.

Comment: Then for an interval [0,1] , if a function is discontinuous at dyadic rationals ( finite binary expansions ) and continuous at other points , then is the function continuous or discontinuous ?

Comment: Well, continuous on an interval typically means at every point, hence it would not be continuous. Since it is continuous at other points it is not discontinuous on the interval. When we speak of functions themselves being continuous or discontinuous it often means at every point, as opposed to continuity at a point. Though, these are conventions. You could define things differently and that would be okay. What really matters is everyone understands each other.

Comment: So what you meant for this case is we cannot say whether it s continuous or discontinuous right

Comment: What I'm saying is that on the interval we can say it is neither if we define continuity on the interval as continuous at every point, and discontinuous as discontinuous at every point. Nothing more, nothing less.